# Replicating "openssl dgst" in Postman

Tags: openssl, postman, signature, cryptojs

I am trying to sign requests sent with Postman in a pre-request script.
Currently I am able to manually generate the signature (the "digest") using this shell command:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign privateKey.pem < payload.txt | openssl base64
```

*payload.txt* contains the JSON payload to be signed.
The output is a signature like this one: `MCwCFBxtf5UnNnpYW+4DaaNFBD/0+pu+AhQ54vSnoeoe/smGIySUD1FFra/mpQ==`

It seems that Postman scripts only implement a few JS libraries, and notably CryptoJS ([source here](https://postman-quick-reference-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html)), so I tried to replicate the previous OpenSSL command with CryptoJS.

This is what I ended up with:

```
var privateKey = environment['privateKey'];
var payload = request.data;
var hashDigest = CryptoJS.SHA256(payload);
var hmacDigest = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(hashDigest, privateKey);
var sig = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hmacDigest);
pm.environment.set("signature", sig);
```

But this script does not yield a working signature like the OpenSSL command. In fact the format are different: not the same length, and CryptoJS's one is deterministic, whereas OpenSSL's one is not.

Would you have some clue?

Comment: There's an open feature request for that on the postman repo: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4264. In case you found another javascript library than CryptoJS that is able of solving the issue, you could save the whole library into an environment variable and then use it. Similar to what is described here: https://community.postman.com/t/how-we-can-use-faker-in-postman-v-7-2/5916/8